# Rails How to change a table which populate a combobox in the same form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, combobox

I have a table to save my requisities, and this requisities can be from more than 1 table (polymorphic), as describe bellow.

```
class Requisite < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :this,       :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :require,    :polymorphic => true
end

class PlayerElement < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :element
    belongs_to :player_space
    has_one :execution, :as => :what
    has_one :requisite, :as => :this
    has_one :requisite, :as => :require
end

class PlayerArmament < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :armament
    belongs_to :player_space
    has_one :requisite, :as => :this
    has_one :requisite, :as => :require
end
```

The form is listed bellow with static second combobox, but I wanna have a form with the second combobox depends on first one.

```
<%= form_for(@requisite) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :this_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :this_type, :value => params["type"] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :this_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :this_id, :value => params["id"] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :require_type %><br>
    <%= f.select :require_type, ([["PlayerElement","PlayerElement"],["PlayerArmament","PlayerArmamentdiv>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :require_id %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select(:require_id, @player_elements, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :qty %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :qty %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lvl %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :lvl %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In case the first combobox selected PlayerArmament, the second combobox must change from:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:require_id, @player_elements, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
```

To:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:require_id, @player_armaments, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
```

How can I do this ???

Comment: Using Javascript, you can change the values being shown in the second combo box based on what was selected in the first.

Comment: Can you post your view code for the form?

Comment: Murthy, I imagine I resolve with Javascript, but I do not know Javascript, and who I have to put this in Rails framework.